# Giltab CI and images platform

Tags: spring, rspec, arm, gitlab-ci, x86-64

I have a Rails app and the whole CI on Gitlab.

I've built for the for time a GitlabCI image (stored on Gitlab Registry) and I'm facing an issue with Spring.

When I use the image built from a Macbook with M2 processor, Spring is not found.

Here is the diff between bad and good job.

```
# Good
[TEST PROF INFO] Spring detected

# Bad
Starting Spring server with `/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-4.1.1/bin/spring server --background` timed out after 20 seconds
```

When it's `bad` it leads to `Migrations are pending.` and job fails.

I was able to fix building the image (for the CI only) with `--platform linux/amd64`

Locally, no issue with Spring, no pending migration etc.

More important, if I force the run of the migration before running `rspec` it fails anyway for the same reason.

I honestly don't know what's happening with Spring on ARM on Gitlab Runner.

Here is my Dockerfile to build the image.

```
FROM ruby:3.2.2

EXPOSE 3000

LABEL "maintainer"="benebrice"
LABEL "app_type"="backend"
LABEL "service_type"="API"

USER root

ARG RAILS_ENV=development

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.4.19
ENV APP /rails

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release
# Yarn source
RUN curl -sS "https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg" | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-key adv --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com

# PSQL 14
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y net-tools nodejs postgresql-client-14 cmake nano zsh unzip yarn python3-pip jq psmisc

WORKDIR $APP

# Fix slow IRB issue
# issue: https://github.com/ruby/irb/issues/43
RUN echo 'IRB.conf[:USE_MULTILINE] = false' > ~/.irbrc
RUN echo 'set linenumbers' > ~/.nanorc

# Main app
COPY Gemfile /rails/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /rails/Gemfile.lock

RUN gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION

# Main app
RUN bundle install
RUN gem clean

RUN rm -r /rails/*

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh

# Start the main process.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb", "config.ru"]
```

Comment: Can you provide the Dockerfile you used to build the image? Is your GitLab runner using ARM architecture or is it using AMD64?

Comment: Hi @sytech I've added the Dockerfile. For the GitLab runner, I have no idea. I thought it was deduced by the Digest. 

Comment: I'm only using the shared runner. Do I need to specify something? 
Actually, several developers with different computers can build the image. I would like to solve the issue for all of them so regardless the computer which built the image, pipeline is still fine.